# Estou tendo problemas para separar um inteiro de uma variável

Tags: c, c++

Bom dia Pessoal, estou tendo problemas na seguinte questão.

Escreva um programa que recebe um horário fornecido pelo usuário como um único
inteiro (hhmmss) e escreve a hora na forma: hh:mm:ss. O programa usa uma função
que recebe o inteiro contendo o horário e devolve esse horário em variáveis
separadas: hora, minuto e segundo.

Já pensei em varias maneiras isso e tudo que consegui desenvolver até agora, porém o resultado sai bem estranho como por exemplo eu insiro 131010 ele me retorna: 3960832: 0: 4200992

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
 int horario(int hhmmss,int hh,int mm,int ss);
 int main(){
 int hhmmss, hh, mm, ss;
 horario(hhmmss,hh,mm,ss);

  printf("%d: %d: %d ",(&hh,&mm,&ss));
}
 int horario(int hhmmss,int hh,int mm,int ss){
  printf("Insira um horario no formato hhmmss: \n");
  scanf("%d",&hhmmss);
  hh = hhmmss/10000;
  mm = (hhmmss % 10000)/100;
  ss = hhmmss % 100;
}
```

Pesso desculpas pelo código enviado como imagem.

Comment: Você está passando parâmetros para sua função **por valor** e está tentando utilizar o resultado de cálculos realizados em sua função na função chamadora (no caso a main). Nz realidade está imprimindo lixo de memória. Pesquise por passagem de parâmetros por referência.

Comment: Ok, agora eu passei o endereço de memória para as 3 variáveis

printf("%d: %d: %d ",(&hh,&mm,&ss)); consegui separar o mm e ss porém o hh ainda continua recebendo lixo de memória

Comment: Então mostre como ficou sua função horário, não como imagem mas sim como texto, como é o recomendado neste site.  [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução 1)** Passagem de parametros por referência (ponteiro):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void horario(int n, int *h, int *m, int *s)
{
    *h = n / 10000;
    *m = (n % 10000) / 100;
    *s = n % 100;
}

int main(void)
{
    int entrada, horas, minutos, segundos;
    printf("Insira um horario no formato hhmmss: ");
    scanf("%d",&entrada);
    horario(entrada, &horas, &minutos, &segundos);
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", horas, minutos, segundos);
    return 0;
}
```

**Solução 2)** Retornando uma `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct hora_s
{
    int horas;
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
} hora_t;

hora_t horario(int n)
{
    hora_t h;
    h.horas = n / 10000;
    h.minutos = (n % 10000) / 100;
    h.segundos = n % 100;
    return h;
}

int main(void)
{
    int entrada;
    hora_t h;
    printf("Insira um horario no formato hhmmss: ");
    scanf("%d",&entrada);
    h = horario(entrada);
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h.horas, h.minutos, h.segundos);
    return 0;
}
```